# How to lay out 2,3 or 4 boxes next to each other via HTM/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have layout where 2,3 or 4 boxes need to be positioned next to each other in a parent container. If 2 boxes are inserted then each need to take 50% of parent container space. If 3 then each takes 1/3 of parent space and 4 then each takes 1/4 of parent space. How would I achieve this? I was thinking of using `display:table` via css would there be any better solution though? I need to support IE8+

Comment: I imagine you've investigated a handful of ways to go about this; what have you tried and what were your concerns specifically with what you tried?

Comment: Flexbox was created for what you want, but IE support starts at version 10. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I hope to be of your help, i made a small example:

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="contents">example</div>
    <div class="contents">example</div>
    <div class="contents">example</div>
    <div class="contents">example</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:optional;
    height:auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #f00;
    display: table;
}
.cont .conten {
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    position: static;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Depending on the contents of the divs("content") were adjusted